# mnesia table not present vs table not loaded

Tags: erlang, mnesia

How can I tell the difference between a table not being present in the schema and a table that has not yet loaded?

I am currently using mnesia:wait_for_tables() with a relatively large timeout to detect a table, but this is loose (what happens if the table actually takes a long time to start) and time consuming (if the table is really not there).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe try...

```
lists:member(table_name, mnesia:table_info(schema, tables)).
```

It's only a guess, but it could be the basis for an experiment if no one else has a definitive answer.

Comment: This seems to work for me.  My only lingering concern is that the schema table may not be loaded at this point, so to combat that risk I added mnesia:wait_for_tables([schema], 2000) before calling table_info().  I am now satisfied.

Answer (score 1):

mnesia:table_info/2 may help.

1. If you know the table names in advance and you want to know which nodes have data,

   ```
   mnesia:table_info(TableName, StorageType).
   ```

   StorageType should be one of

   ```
   ram_copies, disc_copies or disc_only_copies.
   ```
2. or, if you want to know the local node has table copy, just

   ```
   mnesia:table_info(TableName, storage_type).
   ```

   If the local node does NOT have a copy, this returns 'unknown'.

Comment: If the table is not in the schema at all, table_info() will raise an exit exception rather than 'unknown'.

Comment: Thakns for comment. I only consider the case where table exists somewhere. Including the case tables does not exists anywhere, use mnesia:table_info with catch.